# integers to boolean always gives me 1

Tags: casting, arduino

I am new programming.

I am trying to convert integers to boolean in arduino, but I always get 1.
Help me please:

```
/////////////////////////////////
boolean booleanValue;
int val;


void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);// connect to the serial port
}

void loop () {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    val = Serial.read();//// read the serial port
      boolean booleanValue = !!val;


    Serial.println(booleanValue);
  }

}
```

Comment: If `val` is 0, then you should not get 1.

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to SO.  I think you have a pretty good question, but it would be helpful if we knew exactly what you are doing to produce the problem.  What input exactly have you tried?  Which line exactly is showing you "1"?  How have you confirmed that the previous steps are working?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Serial.parseInt()` instead of `Serial.read()`.

`Serial.read()` returns the bit pattern for the input byte, hex 30 for the character "0". It would return 0 if the input were a null byte, not a digit, letter etc.

Alternatively, you could check for the input being exactly 0x30, treat that as false, and treat all other inputs as true.

You should try to isolate the code you suspect, and make sure you know exactly what input is it working with. In this case, inserting `Serial.println(val,HEX);` immediately after the read would have told you the problem was in how you were reading, rather than in the conversion.